# Output Search Results in Multiple Files to One File in Python

Tags: python, file, io

I'm trying to parse log files, and need to be able to search within the logs for specific terms. The directory contains many files. I want to iterate over each file in the directory looking for a specific term, if found, I want output the line(s) containing that term to only one output file. I've been able to iterate over the directory and find the files containing the search, and print out, or write the filenames to an output file, but I've been unable to get the actual lines to write to the file. Below is what I have so far. I know it's basic, I'm still learning...

```
# import libraries
import os
from datetime import date 

# output function
def output_logs():
         with open(f'Parsed Logs_{today}.csv', 'w') as fo:       
                fo.writelines(f"Total Number of Files in Directory is: {file_count}\n")
                fo.writelines(f"Total Number of Files Containing '{string_to_find}' is: {search_count}\n")
                for docs in search_docs:
                    fo.writelines(docs)
                    fo.writelines('\n')
                

# variables
path_dir = "C:/Users/me/Desktop/logs July 8 to 17/2022-7-8/"  
today = str(date.today())

# iterate over files in a directory
file_list = []
file_count = 0
for file in os.listdir(path_dir):
    file_list.append(file)
    file_count += 1
# print(f"Total Number of Files in Directory is: {file_count}\n")

# search for a specific string in files
string_to_find = "SEVERE"
directory_to_search = path_dir
search_docs = []
search_count = 0
for file in os.listdir(directory_to_search):
    with open(directory_to_search + file) as f:
        if string_to_find in f.read():
            search_docs.append(file)
            search_count += 1
# print(search_docs)
# print(f"Total Number of Files Containing '{string_to_find}' is: {search_count}")

# call the output function from above
output_logs()
```

The output I'm wanting should look like this:

[2022-02-14T19:02:01.669-0400] [Payara 5.2020.6] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=224 _ThreadName=payara-executor-service-task] [timeMillis: 1644879721669] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Exception while visiting javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.class of size 744

If it spans multiple lines, I need to capture the entire statement and write to output file, and I need to do this for every file in the directory at once.

The term I'm currently searching is SEVERE. If the line contains SEVERE, it needs to be added to the output file.

Comment: Try using ```f.readlines()``` then iterate over each line as an item in a list. If your log entry spans multiple lines, then I would suggest spliting the log file with however it is delimited. If you post some sample data it will be easier to help.

Comment: Thank you @1extralime. What I posted above is a sample of the data I'm trying to parse. From the opening [ all the way to the end is an example of what one instance of the log entry could look like. There may be some variations of content, but the structure is the same. There's really no clear delimeter, as there are [], /, and 'spaces' throughout the lines.